# Random posts from a pool of posts

Tags: posts, get-posts

Right now my site shows 3 random posts at the end of my single page articles. Here is the code I use and it works (with comments):

```
                    <?php 
                    $rand_posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&orderby=rand&post_type=any&cat=-15');    
                        /*  
                        Alternative Expression: (include all post types, exclude catefory 'site' in the following code we define the post types explicitly instead of 'any'")
                        $args = array(
                        'orderby'       => 'rand',
                        'posts_per_page'   => 3,
                        'category'      => -1,
                        'post_type'     => array( 'post', 'page', 'oldp' )
                        );
                        $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
                        */

                        foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
```

I would like the random posts to be my best posts, that is to be from a pool of posts I will choose or somehow identify. How can this be done.

I also have a code for random quotes that is quite simple and I wonder if I could use something as simple as that to specify the random posts pool:

```
$quotes = array(
    'Quote1',
    'Quote2',
    'Quote3',
); 
return $quotes[rand(0, count($quotes)-1)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick & simple: You could simply use `post__in` in your query with the post IDs of those in your pool, though it might be less easy to maintain when you add and remove posts.

Or you could use a meta field and change your query to include it, see the [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). Then either set that field manually in the post editor or use a Plugin (Advanced Custom Fields, Custom Field Suite etc pp) to generate a fancy looking checkbox.

To use the custom field version, change your get_posts() call from

```
$rand_posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&orderby=rand&post_type=any&cat=-15');
```

to

```
$rand_posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&orderby=rand&post_type=any&cat=-15&meta_key=toppost&meta_value=1');
```

and you should be up and running, assuming the meta field you're adding is called `toppost` and you've set its value to 1 for the top posts you want in your pool.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you please post the specific code, to see what it would look like? Thanks

Comment: That'd be as simple as adding `meta_key=toppost&meta_value=1` to your `get_posts()` call and adding a the meta value to your posts.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the complete code. Right now it is too fragmented and I can't choose it as best answer.

Comment: It's copy & paste-ready now.

Comment: basically order by rand should never be used as it is just bad performance. Better thing is to get all posts and "rand" on php side. this way the request can be cached by all the wordpress caching plugins which do such things (object cache plugins for example)... Or rand first and get only the post that you got from it. It is will better performance for the specific request, but not great for caching.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun Would this be too complicated? Is it possible to provide a code example?

Comment: @IXN, it is actually very basic idea that just follows the answer.... get all the posts without randomizing them, and then use php rand function http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php to decide which of them you want to display. It assumes that the number of possible posts is not very big. If the number is big there is a trade off of DB performance vs PHP performance which is harder to quantify.